# DEP0001: Unexpected Error: SmartDeviceException - Incompatible version of the RPC stub. [0x80131500] during UWP app deployment to Windows phone

Tags: deployment, uwp, windows-phone, rpc, stub

I'm encountering an error while deploying a UWP app to a Windows phone device using Visual Studio. The error message is:

DEP0001: Unexpected Error: SmartDeviceException - Incompatible version of the RPC stub. [0x80131500]

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

```
Updated Visual Studio and Windows 10 SDK
Repaired Visual Studio installation
Verified Hyper-V is enabled and emulator VM is running
Cleared relevant cache files
Reinstalled Windows 10 Mobile Emulator
```

Unfortunately, none of these solutions have resolved the issue.

Here's my environment:

```
Visual Studio version: 2017 Community 15.9.60
Windows 10 version: 22H2 Build 19045.4046
Windows 10 SDK version: 10586
Target Windows phone device: Win 10 Mobile Enterprise 1703
```

I'm hoping to get help with:

```
Identifying the root cause of the "Incompatible version of the RPC stub" error.
Finding a solution to successfully deploy my UWP app to the Windows phone device.
```

Any insights or suggestions from the community would be greatly appreciated!

Please note: I've already tried the common solutions mentioned online, so I'm looking for more specific advice based on my situation.